# how to find and remove illegal point in spatstat

Tags: spatstat

I am trying to plot a ppp object and i get the following error:

```
In plot.ppp(x = list(window = list(type = "polygonal", xrange = c(556681.496972543,  :
  1 illegal points also plotted
```

Earlier it has also shown me the following error:

```
Warning message:
1 point was rejected as lying outside the specified window
```

How may I find this point and remove it from within R or using spatstat within R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is kept as an attribute so you can inspect it. To access the rejected point use `attr(x, "rejects")` where `x` is the name of your `ppp`.

The attribute is discarded by almost any other operation than `plot`, so to permanently get rid of the rejected point you could use `x <- as.ppp(x)` where again `x` is the name of your `ppp`.